# Варианты оптимизации загрузки картинок на сайт

Tags: оптимизация, изображения, оптимизация-сайтов, облачное-хранилище

Какие есть варианты чтобы оптимизировать загрузку изображений на сайт?

Comment: а что конкретно оптимизировать хотите? Скорость загрузки? Размер картинки? Качество сжатия?

Comment: @tym32167 скорее всего он про хранение

Comment: Изначально у меня все картинки хранились на том же хосте что и сайт, но потом мне посоветовали создать AWS s3 и там хранить и получать картинки для сайта и сказали что скорость загрузки картинок будет выше, но по факту скорость такая же.
Правда ли скорость на s3 должна быть выше? Если да то что я могу делать не так?

Если нет, то как можно увеличить скорость загрузки картинок на сайт?

Comment: Ваш вопрос слишком общий. Скорость загрузки картинок - вещь абстрактная. Она может зависеть не только от выбранного хостера, но и от региона, где вы смотрите сайт, от размеров картинки, и ещё 100500 факторов. Вы следуете каким то советам не понимая, как именно это поможет. Вы сначала выясните, отчего у вас картинки грузятся медленно - а потом решайте проблему. Может, вам их лучше хранить в меньшем разрешении и/или превью для них добавить и/или хостера выбрать географически поближе к вашей целевой аудитории, а может просто кеширование настроить на сервере и клиенте или сменить формат картинок.